# ASP.NET Hyperlink control will not navigate to url

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, navigation

I have a hyperlink that does not navigate to the set URL.  It is dead simple I have no idea what is wrong.
The link in my aspx page:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkLostPass" runat="server"  
   Text="Forgot username or password?" NavigateUrl="~/test.aspx" Target="_self">    </asp:HyperLink>
```

When I click the hyperlink the test page doesn't load, the navigation bar shows:
    theserver:33072/websitename/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebHCV3%2ftest.aspx

and I stay on Default.aspx.

There is no code behind written for test.aspx (simple page that reads 'TEST') and it resides in the same folder as Default.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by adding the following to your `web.config` file:

```
  <location path="test.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: This is a quick workaround, but i think the applicant must know about forms authentication mechanism.

Comment: Yes or OP can also move that file outside of the account folder, If recall , it will avoid such issue

Comment: I have to familiarize myself better with forms authentication.  So, response.redirect keeps all activity within the same authorization scope but if it is a hyperlink I have to explicitly set the authorization. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the url pointed to at ~/test.aspx is sitting behind your Forms Authentication path and is therefore being redirected by the server to what you have setup as your login page (Note: the ReturnUrl=path in your navigation bar.

Please review your web.config entries and ensure your path to test.aspx is allowed to be viewed by Anonymous requests.

Answer (score 1):

You have used authentication in your application. you are redirected to default because root directory has restricted except for default.aspx.

Just check your web.config file.